# Can SWC files be created in DEBUG and RELEASE version by using Conditional Compilation constants?

Tags: flash, release, flashdevelop, swc, conditional-compilation

Is there a way to compile `SWC` files in different targets (Debug vs. Release) similarly how you can compile a SWF file with the AS3 Conditional Compiler constants?

This link shows how `SWF` files can be compiled with predefined compiler constants:
http://flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=AS3_Conditional_Compilation

But I need to know how to achieve this with `SWC` files instead.

***Note: I'm using FlashDevelop (Windows 7) to create the `SWC` (if that's any help to refine the answer).***

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is possible using FlashBuilder 4+ by changing the build settings of the project before exporting as an swc. I do not know the limitations of FlashDevelop. Can you get access to FlashBuilder?

Comment: I have access to it at work but I prefer sticking to FlashDevelop for my own development (I find it much more efficient and lightweight to use). But thanks, didn't know FB4 could do that!